# get values from array list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, return-value

i need to get and check the values from each array and place it after in html textbox.
thanks for anybody who can help.

```
    var office = [
            {display: "11*23", value: "11*23",id:"11*23" },
            {display: "11.4x16.2", value: "11.4x16.2" },
            {display: "13*19", value: "13*19" },
            {display: "15*22", value: "15*22" },
            {display: "16.2*23.7", value: "16.2*23.7" },
            {display: "18*25", value:"18*25" }];

        var dorina = [
            {display: "11*23", value:"11*23" },
            {display: "13*19", value: "13*19" },
            {display: "15*22", value: "15*22" },
            {display: "", value: "" }];

        var pocket= [
            {display: "18*25", value: "18*25" },
            {display: "20*30", value: "20*30" },
            {display: "24*30", value: "24*30" },
            {display: "24*34", value: "24*34" },
            {display: "26*36", value: "26*36" },
            {display: "30*40", value: "30*40" },
            {display: "32*42", value: "32*42" },
            {display: " ", value: " " },
            {display: " ", value: " " }];
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

See [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/9m3ee0m6/)

```
  //data can also be a string to a url that returns JSON
jinqJs().from(office, dorina, pocket).select(function(row) {
    text += 'display: ' + row.display + ' value: ' + row.value + '\n'; 
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByName()` function to select the input field & change the placeholder for each one, following is the code:

```
document.getElementsByName('FieldName')[0].placeholder='your value';
```